# SQL count with and without WHERE in 2 columns

Tags: sql, select, count, union, where-clause

I tried several ways to use UNION and JOIN but I couldn't get it.

This is my table:

```
      name    gender
---------------------
Row1 | joe     m
Row2 | becky   f
Row3 | sam     m 
Row4 | simon   m
Row5 | olivia  f
Row6 | bill    m
```

Now I would like to have a SQL query that can COUNT all and only the female entries:

```
      all  female
---------------------
Row1 | 6     2
```

So I tried:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS all FROM table
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS female FROM table WHERE gender = 'f'
```

Which gives me:

```
      all
---------
Row1 | 6 
Row2 | 2
```

How can I have the result in 2 columns? And is there a way to do this in 1 SELECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS all, 
    SUM(CASE gender 
            WHEN 'f' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS female 
FROM table
```

[Added a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57e07b7/5)

Answer (score 2):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  sum(1) "all",
  sum(case when gender = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) female
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99a636c4064914df27b44cc07940de87)

Answer (score 0):

You could use that `COUNT()` does not count `NULL` values. Try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "all", COUNT(NULLIF(gender, 'm')) AS female
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

use case

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS all, sum( case when gender='f'then 1 else 0 end) as f FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is to use a `cte` or `temptable` like:

```
;with cte as (
   select count(*) as FemaleCount
   from mytable
   where gender='f'
)
select AllCount = (select count(*) from mytable)
       FemaleCount = (select FemaleCount from cte)
```

Note: `cte` works in Sql Server.